# cocoa pods update broke something, now "pod update" produces errors

Tags: ios, rubygems, cocoapods

I upgraded from CocoaPods 1.3.1 to 1.5.3. I'm using Xcode 9.2

I have an issue with pod install. Expected it to install all pod dependencies correctly.

Instead, got the following error halfway through:

> LoadError - cannot load such file -- macho
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:432:in `rescue in dynamic_binary?'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:427:in`dynamic_binary?'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:164:in `block in vendored_dynamic_frameworks'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:163:in`select'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:163:in `vendored_dynamic_frameworks'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:172:in`vendored_static_frameworks'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/sandbox/file_accessor.rb:238:in `vendored_static_artifacts'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/aggregate_xcconfig.rb:56:in`block in generate'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/aggregate_xcconfig.rb:56:in `each'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/aggregate_xcconfig.rb:56:in`any?'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/aggregate_xcconfig.rb:56:in `generate'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/generator/xcconfig/aggregate_xcconfig.rb:39:in`save_as'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/target_installer.rb:107:in `update_changed_file'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/aggregate_target_installer.rb:96:in`block in create_xcconfig_file'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/aggregate_target_installer.rb:93:in `each'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/aggregate_target_installer.rb:93:in`create_xcconfig_file'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/aggregate_target_installer.rb:18:in `block in install!'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:142:in`message'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/aggregate_target_installer.rb:14:in `install!'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:181:in`block (2 levels) in install_libraries'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:179:in `each'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:179:in`block in install_libraries'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:142:in `message'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:167:in`install_libraries'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator.rb:65:in `generate!'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:184:in`block in generate_pods_project'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:183:in`generate_pods_project'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:119:in `install!'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in`run'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in`run'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/pod:23:in`load'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
>   /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'

### CocoaPods Environment

pod env

#### Stack

`CocoaPods : 1.5.3
Ruby : ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
RubyGems : 2.5.0
Host : Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G1408)
Xcode : 9.2 (9C40b)
Git : git version 2.14.3 (Apple Git-98)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 0394a8486df6a54691151f75289676af4c7237d5`

#### Installation Source

Executable Path: /Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/pod

#### Plugins

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2
cocoapods-plugins : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try : 1.1.0

#### Podfile

```
ruby
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'IGapp' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

  # Pods for IGapp
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
pod 'TOCropViewController'

  target 'IGappTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'IGappUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
```

end

I've tried uninstalling and installing ruby macho, but it doesn't help.

gem which macho
`/Users/kdanielwong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/ruby-macho-1.2.0/lib/macho.rb`

Any idea what else I can try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to a comment on [the cocoapods GitHub repository](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7867#issuecomment-399726757), I went to edit the file in the top of the stacktrace (file_accessor.rb) and changed the top line from: `autoload :MachO, 'macho'` to `require 'macho'`

And the issue went away!

Answer (score 7):

A method that worked for me is removing the current version or versions:

`gem uninstall ruby-macho`

And then reinstalling it again with:

`gem install ruby-macho --source=http://rubygems.org`

Check this thread https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6602.

Comment: I had seen this and tried it, but it didn't work in my case, with cocoa pods 1.5.3. It appears to work for some people who encountered a similar problem upgrading to coco pods 1.1.1 or 1.2 in 2017, though.